# Analysis of whole sample based of individual posteriors

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, sample, posterior

I have a sample of N objects for which I have a model that fits some parameters (say `param1`, `param2`). I have modeled them using MCMC, so I have an estimate of the posteriors of `param1` and `param2` for each individual object. I would like to use these results to study the whole sample, in particular, the overall distribution of `param1`, `param2`, and a possible correlation between them. However, I am having a hard time understanding how I should do it:

1) On the one hand, I can think of the set of `param1` and `param2` values as data points (and use confidence intervals as their uncertainties). I could, for example, create a histogram of the obtained `param1` values, and say something like "60% of these have `param1` < 10". With this idea, it makes sense for me that I could sum all the MCMC steps for each object, and I will get a histogram of the whole sample that accounts for the uncertainty of each individual `param1` estimate (in a process similar to a kernel density estimate).

2) On the other hand, posteriors require probabilities to be be multiplied, not summed, so in some sense it also sounds like I could multiply all the individual posteriors for `param1` to obtain the overall posterior. However, I am confused here, since I have individual MCMC runs. If multiplication is the correct way, I guess I would bin the parameter space and multiply all the individual distributions. Is this the correct approach? Note that these objects are independent and there is no universal value for these `param1` and `param2`, i.e., I do not expect them to converge to one single value when comparing all these objects.

3) Finally, I have exactly the same doubt for the comparison of `param1` vs `param2`. If I simply plot `param1` vs `param2` based on the obtained values, there is a clear correlation. However, I was also considering building the 2D distribution from the individual MCMC runs, and I am again unsure about what the proper way would be.

What would be the correct approach in this case, and why?

Edit: I think the confusion may arise in defining what I am doing as "computing the posterior `param1` and `param2` for the whole sample", which may not be the case. As an example, if only one object has a posterior value of 0 at a given point, that doesn't mean that the whole sample has a 0 probability there (pretty much the opposite, all but one objects have some probability at that point!).